# .env file states that it is uploaded, yet when I look on my server, its not there.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

Im using Cap3 to deploy my application.

im using dotenv-rails with the .env file holding my secrets. This does not get pushed to git, which we deploy from.

in my stack track it shows the .env file gets uploaded into the releases/ directory, yet when I go look... its not there.

Gem File.

```
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-env'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-faster-assets', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'capistrano-postgresql', '~> 4.2.0'
  gem "capistrano-resque", "~> 0.2.2", require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-safe-deploy-to'
  gem 'capistrano-secrets-yml'
  gem 'capistrano-slackify'
  gem 'capistrano-ssh-doctor', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
```

Any help would be great

Comment: files with prefix "." are hidden by default. Did you double check you have listed all files including hidden files in that directory?

Comment: duh. Ok. but it doesn't seem to be loading my .env file at all. it creates one. 

the code in my deploy.rb is 
Capistrano::Env.use do |env|
  env.add 'HOGE', 'hage'
  env.formatter = :dotenv #=> default is :ruby, but it is deprecated now.
  env.filemode = 0644 #=> default is 0640.
end

and the env.add seems to add the HOGE, hage combo, yet, not the .env file that is on my local.

Comment: You'd better update your question since it is too hard to read the code in comment. Or it would be better to start another question.

Comment: I agree with Yang. Throw out another question regarding .env not being loaded, as it will be easier to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On the server, enter `ls -a` which will show all files, even those prefixed by a ".", which are hidden by default and not shown when using just `ls`